# Can nor be used with any negative (negation/negative word)?

Tags: conjunctions, grammaticality-in-context

Firstly, I want to show an example I got from Oxford Learner's Grammar.

> The electricity had been disconnected – **nor** was there any water.

And **nor** ―according to OALD― is used before a positive verb to agree with something negative that has just been said. It also means "and not". Since the sentence above can be written as:

> The electricity had been disconnected by someone ...

I'm assuming disconnect is a verb, although perhaps it's just "had been + adjective"? (I'm not sure). Regardless of my confusion whether it's a verb or adjective ―come to my question―, can I use "nor" like this sentence below:

**I hate her **nor** care about her.**

In general, my point is, is it allowed to use this form below?

> verb (negative meaning) + somebody/something + **nor** + verb
> (positive meaning)

I did a quick search, but didn't find a satisfying answer. There was a similar question to this question, the answerer suggested to use **OR + DOESN'T/DON'T** instead of **NOR** which is actually not answering this question that is 'Why can't I?'

Comment: Hate is negative in the sense of being an unpleasant emotion, but it isn't grammatically negative. I think OALD means something including _not_ or a prefix such as _un-_ or _dis-_. (Yes, _disconnected_ is a verb.) You would have to say **I neither like her nor care about her.**

Comment: Also, I don't like her, nor do I care about her. That is similar  to the Oxford's example. In other words, nor can be used with neither.